# How does the topology of the manifold matter in bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

When dealing with (locally trivial and smooth) bundles $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ in differential geometry, one speaks about local trivializations or cocycles, but it seems to me the topology of $E$ and $M$ are forgotten. How does it matter?

For example, is there a example such that the topology of $E$ as a manifold may be different from the topology induced by the bundle structure?

Comment: But trivializations are defined in terms of the topologies.  How are they forgotten?

Comment: When you say trivializations are defined in terms of the topologies, you are referring to @Eric Wofsey answer?

Comment: I’m referring to the  *definition* (which is in his answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology (and smooth structure) of $E$ and $M$ are *not* ignored.  A local trivialization of a smooth $F$-bundle $\pi:E\to M$ over an open subset $U\subseteq M$ is a *diffeomorphism* $\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times F$ which commutes with the maps to $U$.  To say what it means for this to be a diffeomorphism, you use the smooth manifold structure on $U$ (as an open subset of $M$) and also on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ (as an open subset of $E$).